# how to get two divs of pictures in te same height

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to make a gallery that when I click on the pictures its opens the same picture but bigger and in other place I used switch break but when I opens another div its take it one line down(because the height I gave the picture) so how I can open another div without take the picture one line down.
Here is the code:

```
<div id="f1" onclick="ShowPic(this)">
    <img id="myImg" src="social/twentyone1%20-%20Copy.jpg" height="70" width="80" />
</div>
<div id="f2" class="flex" onclick="ShowPic(this)">
    <img id="myImg" src="social/twentyone3.jpg" height="70" width="80" />
</div>
<div id="f3" class="flex" onclick="ShowPic(this)">
    <img id="myImg" src="social/twentyone2.jpg" height="70" width="80" />
</div>
</div>
<div id="element" class="pretty">
    <img id="bigPic" src="social/twentyone12.jpg" style="width: 550px; height: 550px; text-align:center" />
</div>
```

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowPic(prev) {
    var bigPic = document.getElementById("bigPic");
    switch (prev.id) {
        case "f1":
            bigPic.src = "social/twentyone1%20-%20Copy.jpg";
            break;
        case "f2":
            bigPic.src = "social/twentyone3.jpg";
            break;
        case "f3":
            bigPic.src = "social/twentyone2.jpg";
            break;
        case "f4":
     }
}
```

[how i can make those 3 "small pictures" to be in the same line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSAnU.jpg)

Comment: What do you by *"its take it one line down"*? Do you mean that you have the `div` all on one line and the element `bigPic` moves to the next line when switching `src`'s?

Comment: no when i do another div of the "small pics" its takes them one line down beacuse the hight of the picture if you want i can take a picture of how its looks like

Comment: Just provide a runnable example with example pictures, your explanation of the issue isn't very clear.

Comment: i posted a picture

Comment: Use `float: left` on your div's containing the smaller pictures.

Comment: thank you but now my light blue background has gone there is a way to fix it?

Comment: I don't have your code, I wouldn't know what the issue is.

Comment: if you look at the picture i posted you can see those 3 pictures were in a big div and in that div i wrote style="backgournd color=light blue
thats it